# C++ Using base class pointers outside of function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, radix

I have a base class and several derived classes. Before I used one container to manage an object but now I have can have several differnt types of students in this case, meaning that I have decided to use base class pointer to manage it. However I am not sure how I can work on the object outside the function that created it. Below is what I have done before to manage objects. Is there something similar to manage containers with base class pointers?

```
 pointer = new SchoolChild[NoOfChildren];//creates pointer that free up space on memory

 for (int i = 0; i < NoOfChildren; i++)
{
    pointer[i].display();
}
```

Comment: That just creates an array to store your SchoolChild object pointers. Change it to the base class and then you'll have an array of base pointers. Somewhere else you'll need to set new SchoolChild objects and any other derived types into the base pointer array. This will need to happen before you try to call display() on each array entry otherwise it's trying to call the display() method on NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would move from managing an *array* of *values* to an *array* of *pointers*:

```
// from this (pointer to SchoolChild)
SchoolChild* children = new SchoolChild[NoOfChildren];

children[0].name = "name";


// to this (pointer to SchoolChild pointer)
SchoolChild** children = new SchoolChild*[NoOfChildren];

children[0] = new SchoolChild; // allocate each element
children[0]->name = "name";
```

You also have more deleting to do, needing to delete every element of the array as well as the array itself.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NoOfChildren; ++i)
    delete children[i]; // delete each element
delete[] children; // delete[] the array itself
```

Better to use *containers* and *smart pointers* to manage all that for you:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SchoolChild>> children(NoOfChildren);

children[0]->name = "name";
```

There is no need to delete anything here because the `std::unique_ptr`s will delete the contained `SchoolChild` objects and the `std::vector` will delete the `std::unique_ptr` elements.